# Tidying up Gradle dependencies using Closure

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I read [this post](https://alexfu.github.io/android/2017/11/07/experimenting-with-gradle-dependencies.html) about how to tidy up gradle dependencies, the implementation give something like this:

```
def dependencyGroup(Closure closure) {
    closure.delegate = dependencies
    return closure
}

def ui = dependencyGroup {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:27.0.0"
}

def network = dependencyGroup {
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.5.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
}

dependencies {
    ui()
    network()
}
```

In addition to lose the quick fixing for upgrading dependencies version.
What are the disadvantages, drawbacks or downsides of using this way?

I would want to make a discussion over this, any opinion or feedback is very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose the quick fixing for upgrading dependencies version"? From what I can see, that is just a DSL sugar.

Comment: I mean the *lint* checking over the string of the dependency. The functionality that informs you there is a new version.

Comment: @crgarridos so, what do you prefer? do you still use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

One constraint I found is when you declare a `dependencyGroup` using `def`.
It will define your group locally, then isn't possible to call it from other gradle files. To solve this you can use :

```
ext.myDependencyGroup = dependencyGroup {
    implementation ...
}
```